# Confusion matrix in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

how can I create a confusion matrix in BQ, where the labels in the first column of the matrix are coming from `label1`, and labels in the first row are from `label2` and the numeric values inside the matrix are the counts of `label1` matches `label2`, e.g.

raw data:

```
  with data as (
    select 'A' as label1, 'A' as label2 union all
    select 'A',           'B' union all
    select 'A',           'C' union all
    select 'A',           'A' union all
    select 'A',           'A' union all
    select 'B',           'B' union all
    select 'B',           'C' union all
    select 'B',           'B' union all
    select 'B',           'A' union all
    select 'C',           'C' union all
    select 'C',           'C' union all
    select 'C',           'A' union all
    select 'C',           'C'
   )
```

confusion matrix (output):

```
       A   B   C    <--label2
    A  3   1   1
    B  1   2   1
    C  1   0   3 

    ^
    |
 label1
```

i'm aware of [Pivot](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator) function but not sure how to use it here

Answer (score 0):

ok, i think I figured it out

```
with data as (
  select 'A' as label1, 'A' as label2 union all
  select 'A',           'B' union all
  select 'A',           'C' union all
  select 'A',           'A' union all
  select 'A',           'A' union all
  select 'B',           'B' union all
  select 'B',           'C'  union all
  select 'B',           'B' union all
  select 'B',           'A' union all
  select 'C',           'C' union all
  select 'C',           'C'  union all
  select 'C',           'A' union all
  select 'C',           'C'  
)
select * FROM data
  PIVOT( COUNT(*) FOR label2 IN ('A','B','C'))
```

[image]

the only thing it doesnt allow to use SELECT query inside of IN clause like

```
select * FROM data
  PIVOT( COUNT(*) FOR label2 IN (select distinct label2 from data))
```

so have to enumerate individual  values of label2 like 'A','B','C'  which is not super convenient

```
select * FROM data
  PIVOT( COUNT(*) FOR label2 IN ('A','B','C'))
```

Answer (score 0):

> so have to enumerate individual values of label2 like 'A','B','C' which is not super convenient

You can consider a [dynamic sql](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate) as well.

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  SELECT * FROM data
   PIVOT(COUNT(*) FOR label2 IN ('%s'))
""", (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT label1, "','") FROM data)
);
```

**Query results**

[image]